# TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment (converting a string to int)

Tags: python, string, integer

I am doing a challenge and have run into this problem and i do not know what is going wrong.
code bellow.

## Challenge*

```
generate_list = [
    "9", " ",
    "2", "2", "3", " ",
    "3", "7", "2", " ",
    "3", "6", " ",
    "8", "5", "4", " ",
    "7", "7", "5", " ",
    "8", "0", "7", " ",
]

values = "".join(generate_list)
print(values)

values_list = values.split()
print(values_list)

for i in range(0, len(values)):
    values[i] = int(values[i])
```

converting the string into a integer using a loop

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] and tag a language. Looks like [tag:Python].

Comment: If it is Python, I think you meant to use `values_list` and not `values` in that last `for` loop.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what this code is supposed to do. What output do you expect with this input? Strings are immutable so you can't change individual characters in the string like you try to do with `values[i] = int(values[i])`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you try to change `values` which has the type `str`. Python strings are immutable (i.e. they can't be modified).

You could circumvent this by using a `data collection type` that is mutable. In the code below I made a new list `output` to which all the values will be added.

With that solved a new error pops up:
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '`
This is because you try to convert a space into a number.

You can ignore this error by using `try`.

```py
generate_list = [
    "9", " ",
    "2", "2", "3", " ",
    "3", "7", "2", " ",
    "3", "6", " ",
    "8", "5", "4", " ",
    "7", "7", "5", " ",
    "8", "0", "7", " ",
]

values = "".join(generate_list)
print(values)

values_list = values.split()
print(values_list)

output = []
for character in values:
    try:
        output.append(int(character))
    except ValueError:
        continue

print(output)
# [9, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 2, 3, 6, 8, 5, 4, 7, 7, 5, 8, 0, 7]
```

The same can be done with list comprehension.

```py
print([int(x) for x in generate_list if x != ' '])
# [9, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 2, 3, 6, 8, 5, 4, 7, 7, 5, 8, 0, 7]

print([int(x) for x in values_list])
# [9, 223, 372, 36, 854, 775, 807]
```